# RedirectView vs redirect: in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

which is better to use to redirect url in spring mvc:

```
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("../abc/list.vm"));
```

or

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:DummyRedirectPage.htm");
```

Answer (score 5):

The `ModelAndView` object holds an instance variable that references its view object and which may be either:

- A concrete `View` implementation such as the case when you use:

  ```
  new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("../abc/list.vm"))
  ```
- A `String` object holding the symbolic name of the view prefixed by ***redirect:*** or ***forward:***, such is the case when using:

  ```
  new ModelAndView("redirect:DummyRedirectPage.htm")
  ```

Now when the Spring base web entry, `DispatcherServlet`, is called to render a `View`, it will try to resolve the requested view against the given `ModelAndView` object, either getting the reference to its `View` sub-implementation it its afforded or resolving the `View` and creating it out of the `ModelAndView` view string representation:

```java
protected void render(ModelAndView mv, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    // ...
    View view;
    if (mv.isReference()) {
        // Resolve the view and instantiate it...
    }
    else {
        // No need to lookup: the ModelAndView object contains the actual View object.
        view = mv.getView();
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

*Note that `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView#isReference` returns `true` if the view is a `String` object.*

Given below details, I would assume that the first `ModelAndView` would involve less computation thus may be prefered to the later.